# conditional check of nested array

Tags: php, arrays

I've got the following snippet to dump some info on the screen:

```
for ($i=0; $i < 60; $i++) {
  echo 'output: '.$array[$i]['options'][0]."<br />";
  echo 'output: '.$array[$i]['options'][4]."<br />";
}
```

which outputs the following:

```
output: Lorem ipsum
output: 1
output: dolor sit amet
output: 1
output: consectetur adipiscing elit
output: 0
```

How do I wrap the echo statements in a conditional, so only when `['options'][4] == '1'` it will run?

```
if ($array[$i]['options'][4] == '1') {
...
}
```

Doesn't work and returns nothing, set it to `== '0'` and you'll get everything. 
I've tried assigning it to a variable first, tried converting to ints first, but they all seem to return 0, while an echo displays the value.

Got night-time creative with `foreach loops`, trying to drill down to the items, only resulting in loss of keys where values were still properly read. Its probably something simple, but its been ages since I dabbled with php and arrays.

Comment: if `$array[$i]['options'][4] == '1'`  does not work, var_dump it first and see what does it contain.

Comment: Well last night I could have sworn it didn't, but now it did, must have made some typos..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it with a simple `if`. But why use `txt`? shouldn't you use `options`?

```
if(isset($array[$i]['options'][4]) and $array[$i]['options'][4]==1){
  echo 'output: '.$array[$i]['options'][0]."<br />";
  echo 'output: '.$array[$i]['options'][4]."<br />";
}
```

Comment: Thanks should have asked this last night instead of wasting nightly hours being blind and get a SO within minutes! The ['txt'] vs ['options'] was a typo in making it more SO friendly.